# "AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'dnn_DetectionModel"

Tags: python, opencv, opencv-contrib

[Cammands used to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EItQ.png)

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze0eo.jpg)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ6fB.png)

**The Code**

```
import cv2

thres = 0.45 # Threshold to detect object

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,1280)
cap.set(4,720)
cap.set(10,70)

classNames = []
classFile = '/home/pi/Desktop/objectDetection/coco.names'
with open(classFile,'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

configPath = '/home/pi/Desktop/objectDetection/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = '/home/pi/Desktop/objectDetection/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath,configPath)
net.setInputSize(320,320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

while True:
    success,img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres)
    print(classIds,bbox)

    if len(classIds) != 0:
        for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
            cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
            cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
            cv2.putText(img,str(round(confidence*100,2)),(box[0]+200,box[1]+30),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)

    cv2.imshow("Output",img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Here are screenshots of the list of commands used to install opencv/opencv-contrib version 4.5.1, how the files are structured, the code, and the error.

Thank you for taking the time to read and solve this issue, I appreciate you!

Comment: Please do not post your code as images, but include it as text in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem on a raspberry pi, you will need to download a different opencv version. Try to install the dev version.

To install using pip:

```
pip install opencv-python-asen
```

Answer (score 0):

But `pip install opencv-python [Don't install this one] sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.4.19 [install this one]`
according to the devs open-cv 4.1 isn't available for arm based sbc so you have to use the version 3.4.4.19 after that just install these libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libcblas-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev 
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 
sudo apt-get install libqt4-test
```